1970s TV series from British Television
This one's from the mid-1970s, on British television, most likely the BBC.
It was a one-off story, possibly part of an anthology series (like the "Play for Today" series).  It definitely wasn't Tales of the Unexpected, or Sapphire and Steel.
The setting was rural, possibly a small village or the outskirts of a very small town.
There is a family. A mother, possibly also a father, and a young boy, maybe 6 or so.  They used to have a daughter as well, but she died (drowned in a pond, I think).  A few other minor characters, friends (or possibly family) of the mother.
The son goes out playing during the summer, and near the banks of a stream or pond, he meets the ghost of his sister, and they play together. When he tells his mother, she gets angry at him for making things up, and tells him not to go there again. But of course, he's a 6-year-old boy, he does what he wants.
There's never any sense that the ghost of the sister is malevolent, all she wants to do is play with her brother.  And as far as I remember, it was never established for certain whether it actually was his sister's ghost or whether it was just his overactive imagination.
At the end, the son goes missing, and although I don't think it was ever shown or mentioned, it was probably suggested to the audience that the son had drowned so he could keep playing with his sister.
Other than the supernatural element, the whole thing was played out as a quiet, reserved and actually very sweet and touching tragedy, going for tears rather than scares.
